# IIS Server Error for Wordpress Plugin Installation

Tags: wordpress, iis, plugins, ftp

I have installed WordPress in IIS Server. I need to install some plugins In installation time. It will be asking ftp server username password, so How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that WordPress asks for your FTP credentials when it can’t access the files directly.This is usually caused by PHP running as the user rather than the user that owns your WordPress files.As a workaround you can put your FTP credentials directly in wp-config.php.`define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org:21' );`

Answer (score 0):

just add the code :

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

to the wordpress config file (wp-config.php)